# Azure B2C (IEF/Custom Policy) - State parameter

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I have the following flow for sign in / sign up, when using sign-up:

1. Present user with sign up screen, allow them to enter email/password/name
2. Validate input, then send email (rest api) and set verification attributes in b2c custom extension properties

*User then receives email with verification link*

3. User clicks link from email and gets sent to a new user journey for the return trip
4. New user journey gets parameters from the querystring (email + verif code)
5. B2C validates the verif code + expiry
6. IF user is verified, they're set as verified via custom extension attributes, then sent to the (ASP.NET MVC) application.
7. Here's where I'm stuck - B2C **is** sending the jwt token back to the app, but the user doesn't get 'signed-in'.

Am I missing something at step 7?  I don't have the "state" variable in my querystring, am I expected to build and include it somehow so that B2C and the app can communicate?  I'm lost at this point.  I'd post some of the b2c policy xml but not sure what would even help...

**EDIT: reply to Jas:**

Is that the only way (make an app call b2c for an auth request)?  We have multiple apps that a user can use to sign up through b2c, so I was hoping to avoid having to make changes to each of them.  Instead I was hoping that B2C could tell the app after account verification that "this user is ok".

I did previous look at https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-magic-link (written by you!), but again, was hoping I could avoid having to do that work inside of each of our apps.

Here's an example of the jwt 'id_token' I'm trying to pass to the app:

[id_token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0UVM.png)

Side note: Is 'id_token' the same as 'id_token_hint'?  I couldn't find whether they're the same or different when googling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is send the invite link in the email as a link to the app, eg https://myapp.com?id_token_hint=value.
Then have your apps account controller make an auth request to the policy to complete the account redemption along with an extra query parameter “id_token_hint=value”. Now a proper auth can happen with your applications openId middleware initialised.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jas, I've updated my question for clarification.

Comment: That sample uses id_tokem_hint ;) the problem is if you don’t pass the token to the app to do the auth request, and rather do a direct link to the auth endpoint like the sample, the .NET OpenID Middleware is not initialising a session for the user. So you end up at the app with a token and the app ignores it. You got to do it like I say, link to the app, app passes id token hint into B2C auth request. The only extra work is an endpoint at the app like /redeemInvite that calls the accountController method to start an auth request. And along with it, pass the id token hint from the incoming URL

Comment: The id token hint itself is generated as you are doing, and sending via email. Just it cannot be a direct call to the auth endpoint, must pass the value through your web app.

Comment: Thank you again Jas, let me see if I understand what I can do here.  I have B2C passing back a token (from my screenshot) back to the app, but the app can't handle it.  Therefore, if instead, my app had a method that can accept the token (like /redeeminvite), I could use the token passed to that method as the value for 'id_token_hint' and send the token hint *back* to B2C (via my .net openid middleware > accountcontroller.login or whatever it's called).  The app would then have a session built, and B2C would be able to extract the claims from the token and have the person signed in?

Comment: Yes that makes sense. The sample is what is generating an id_token_hint value. Stick the value in the email link but passing it to your app as a parameter. That controller then needs to call accountController method that passes the id_token_hint as an extra query parameter to the auth request, with your b2c policy id that handles the id_token_hint